# How do I pass data to an email via a triggered send?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, api, email-template, webservices

I'm trying to send a triggered send as is explained here: https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/triggered-sends/triggered-send-send.html#phpsend

I'm trying to display content from the web service in the email via AMPscript as is explained here: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/using_ampscript_with_the_web_service_api/passing_content_to_a_triggered_send_message_at_send_time/

It's not working though. How do I access the attribute values from the triggered send web service in the actual email within the AMPscript? Here is my web service call:

```
require('ET_Client.php');
$myclient = new ET_Client();
$triggeredsend = new ET_TriggeredSend();
$triggeredsend->authStub = $myclient;
$triggeredsend->props = array('CustomerKey' => $customerkey);
$triggeredsend->subscribers = array(array(
    'EmailAddress' => $email, 
    'SubscriberKey' => $email, 
    'Attributes' => array('Name' => 'maxTransport', 'Value' => $maxTransport)
));

$results = $triggeredsend->send();
```

And here is how I'm trying to display the variable in my email:

```
Max Transport = %%maxTransport%%
```

But the variable is not showing up, and I get a validation error for my email that says:

> Errors found in the email HTML Body. Category : Substitution String
>   Personalization error:%%maxtransport%% To fix the problem, please try
>   the following: Make sure that there is not a space or typo within the
>   personalization string in your email. For example, check and correct
>   any spaces between percent signs (%%)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SFSE!

Do you have a `maxTransport` column in the target Data Extension configured in your Triggered Send Definition?  If not, you'll need one.

It's a good practice to wrap personalization strings with the [AttributeValue()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#AttributeValue) function in your email.  Make sure to include the double-quotes around the attribute name.  For example:

```
%%[

var @maxTransport
set @maxTransport = AttributeValue("maxTransport")

]%%
<br>maxTransport: %%=v(@maxTransport)=%%
```

If you use the `AttributeValue()` function, you can check if it's undefined or empty using the `empty()` function, e.g:

```
%%[

if not empty (@maxTransport) then 
  outputLine(concat("maxTransport: ",@maxTransport))
else
  outputLine(concat("maxTransport is empty"))
endif

]%%
```

Comment: So I can't just send a value from the PHP code and consume it in the AMPscript - I have to create a Data Extension in addition? If so, I'm wondering why that's not mentioned here: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/using_ampscript_with_the_web_service_api/passing_content_to_a_triggered_send_message_at_send_time/

Comment: By the way, meant to say thanks for the welcome and thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Aha - I tested it and it is working! The missing piece for me was the AttributeValue() function wrapper. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: ::fist bump:: It's a good practice to configure your Triggered Send Definitions to write to a Data Extension -- just in case you need to verify data or run send previews.  You can also use the DE in suppression scripts, etc.  The DEs must be created with a template: https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/creating_a_data_extension_from_a_template/

Answer (score 0):

For others, I thought I'd post my answer to a similar question on how to do this specifically with ExactTarget and PHP:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/163609/71196